# webbrowser version in visual studio .net winforms

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2017, webbrowser-control

I'm trying out the webbrowser control for UI building. On the up side, interfacing between vb.net and js running on the page wasn't too hard and I got that part settled. On the downside, the webbrowser control seems to be rather limited on the web part.

Now it was my impression that the webbrowser control uses whatever IE is installed on the computer, in this test case it should be IE11. A programmatic check seemed to confirm that, control.version.major returns 11. The reality seems more like IE8 though.

First there were script issues with things like Object.defineProperty and the Class syntax. I got through them by rewriting those parts in medieval javascript. The second hurdle is CSS, it just won't draw border-radius for example, no matter what.

So given that all those missing things were implemented in IE9, I'm thinking the webbrowser control is somehow using IE8 for whatever reason.

Realistically speaking, if I ever were to use this method of UI building in something commercial, I'd probably try using chromium or webkit instead.

Right now I'd just be happy with IE11 though, is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: It's the same version installed on your OS in compatibility mode. Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38514184/3110834).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303