# Get Captcha Image from Web Browser control without using SRC

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, captcha

I know this question might sound familiar and there are plenty of posts out there on google with the same title BUT trust me this is different.

**Editor** : VS2008 (cannot upgrade it due to some technical difficulties)

### Question

How to get **Captcha Image** from a **Web Browser** without using **SRC**?

### Why wouldn't you use SRC?

Here is the site from which i am trying to get my **Captcha Image**
https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login 
(The capta image appears once you type anything in User Name)

Now if you right click on the **Captcha Image** and go to inspect element you will see that the **SRC** of the captcha is:-

[image]

https://services.gst.gov.in/services/captcha?rnd=0.5313315062651027

and whenever you try to go to that link it will give you a captcha that is different from the previous one. That is why i cant use the below code because it shows different captcha than the one showing in the **WebBrowser** right now.

```
HtmlElement element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("imgCaptcha");
string src = element.GetAttribute("src");
pictureBox1.Load(element.GetAttribute("src"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`createControlRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh869512) to create a `controlRange` of non-text elements. Then find the image tag, for example by using `id`, then add the image tag to the control range and call it's [`execCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa704198(v%3dvs.85)) method to execute `Copy` command, and finally, get the image from clipboard:

**.NET 3.5**

Add a reference to `MSHTML`. You can find it by `Microsoft HTML Object Library` under `COM` references and then add `using mshtml;`. Then:

```
IHTMLElement2 body = (IHTMLElement2)webBrowser1.Document.Body.DomElement;
IHTMLControlRange controlRange = (IHTMLControlRange)body.createControlRange();
IHTMLControlElement element = (IHTMLControlElement)webBrowser1.Document
    .GetElementById("imgCaptcha").DomElement;
controlRange.add(element);
controlRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
```

**.NET >= 4.0**

You don't need to add a reference, you can take advantage of `dynamic`:

```
dynamic body = webBrowser1.Document.Body.DomElement;
dynamic controlRange = body.createControlRange();
dynamic element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("imgCaptcha").DomElement;
controlRange.add(element);
controlRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
```

Note:

- Run the code when the document is completed, for example in `DocumentCompleted` event.
- Also you may want to add null checking to the code.
- I used above code to get the google logo from https://www.google.com by id `hplogo`.
- I also tested above code, by browsing https://demos.captcha.com/demos/features/captcha-demo.aspx and finding the captcah image by `c_captchademo_samplecaptcha_CaptchaImage` as id of the captcha image.

Comment: why it's not working on my computer and working on my friend computer? i checked everything like .net version and ie version and ...

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/3110834) It may help @ArefBozorgmehr