# RDLC ReportViewer Browser Not Supported

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a website using ReportViewer version 15.0. When I open in IE 11, it shows error: 
**Browser not supported**

Report Viewer requires a standards compliant browser. Users of Internet Explorer 8 and earlier should switch to a modern browser, or if already using a modern browser target standards mode by adding the header tag to the host page

I used ReportViewer version 10.0 before and it works in IE 11 also in IE8. Can I use ReportViewer version 15.0 in IE 11?
I've tried to add this code in tag `<head>` but it doesn't work

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" >
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Emulate11" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following no-js lines, worked for me

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this form:
Note that is quite preferable to insert the `<meta>` tag right after `<head>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
[...] Other
</head>
```

`IE=edge` forces IE to use the highest mode available, it avoids to trigger compatability mode.
Add `chrome=1` If Google Chrome Frame is still an option (some html validators may flags this entry as an error).

This also applies to the .Net Framework's WebBrowser Control: adding the HTML5 document header and the  tag to a HTML document, causes the WebBrowser to work in IE11 mode, without editing the **`FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`** Registry key, as shown, for example, here:

[How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/7444103)

If you read somewhere that `<!DOCTYPE html>` alone will cause IE to use the highest mode available, you'll be (sometimes) disappointed.