# C# Windows Form - WebBrowser is showing some UI glitch

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control, visual-studio-2019

I am using **VS2019** with **C# .Net 4.7.2**.

I have the below code that is used to create a textbox in **WebBrowser** control by using the following code: -

```
string HTMLCode = "<html>" + Environment.NewLine +
                  "    <head><style>" + Environment.NewLine +
                  "        input[type=text]::-ms-clear {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }" + Environment.NewLine +
                  "    </style></head>" + Environment.NewLine +
                  "<body style=\"margin:0px\" >" + Environment.NewLine +
                  "        <input type='text' id='userName' style=\"border-radius: 5px;font-family: 'Century Gothic';font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px;\" />" + Environment.NewLine +
                  "</body >" + Environment.NewLine +
                  "</html >";

webBrowser1.DocumentText = HTMLCode;
```

Which Looks like this: -

[image]

The Below line is added to remove Clear (X) button from input box which is shown in IE9 or some other versions browser the WebBrowser is using: -

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
```

Below code is used to ensure that it works as close as it can to IE9 (picked from a post in stack overflow, don't have the link of it) and is called at form load event. `SetBrowserFeatureControl();`

```
#region SetBrowserFeatureControl
    public static void SetBrowserFeatureControl()
    {
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx

        // FeatureControl settings are per-process
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

        // make the control is not running inside Visual Studio Designer
        if (String.Compare(fileName, "devenv.exe", true) == 0 || String.Compare(fileName, "XDesProc.exe", true) == 0)
            return;

        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", fileName, GetBrowserEmulationMode()); // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_AJAX_CONNECTIONEVENTS", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_ENABLE_CLIPCHILDREN_OPTIMIZATION", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_MANAGE_SCRIPT_CIRCULAR_REFS", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DOMSTORAGE ", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING ", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_IVIEWOBJECTDRAW_DMLT9_WITH_GDI  ", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DISABLE_LEGACY_COMPRESSION", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_OBJECT", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_SCRIPTURL_MITIGATION", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_STATUS_BAR_THROTTLING", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_TABBED_BROWSING", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_VALIDATE_NAVIGATE_URL", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_DOCUMENT_ZOOM", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_POPUPMANAGEMENT", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBOC_MOVESIZECHILD", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_ADDON_MANAGEMENT", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WEBSOCKET", fileName, 1);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_WINDOW_RESTRICTIONS ", fileName, 0);
        SetBrowserFeatureControlKey("FEATURE_XMLHTTP", fileName, 1);
    }

    private static void SetBrowserFeatureControlKey(string feature, string appName, uint value)
    {
        using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
            String.Concat(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\", feature),
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
        {
            key.SetValue(appName, (UInt32)value, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
    }

    private static UInt32 GetBrowserEmulationMode()
    {
        int browserVersion = 7;
        using (var ieKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer",
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree,
            System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.QueryValues))
        {
            var version = ieKey.GetValue("svcVersion");
            if (null == version)
            {
                version = ieKey.GetValue("Version");
                if (null == version)
                    throw new ApplicationException("Microsoft Internet Explorer is required!");
            }
            int.TryParse(version.ToString().Split('.')[0], out browserVersion);
        }

        UInt32 mode = 11000; // Internet Explorer 11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 Standards mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 11.
        switch (browserVersion)
        {
            case 7:
                mode = 7000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE7 Standards mode. Default value for applications hosting the WebBrowser Control.
                break;
            case 8:
                mode = 8000; // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE8 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 8
                break;
            case 9:
                mode = 9000; // Internet Explorer 9. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE9 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 9.
                break;
            case 10:
                mode = 10000; // Internet Explorer 10. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 mode. Default value for Internet Explorer 10.
                break;
            default:
                // use IE11 mode by default
                break;
        }

        return mode;
    }
    #endregion
```

### Problem

Whenever I click on the input box, the input box shrinks by 1px or 2px and goes back to normal on mouse up.

### Things I have checked

1. There is no other event called for webbrowser other than the one's I mentioned above.
2. Running the same HTML code in browser like (IE9, Chrome) doesn't show this bug.

*To actually see it you have to run the above code.*

Comment: Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of your HTML.

Comment: @noseratio the bug wasn't fixed by that.

Comment: What about `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`?

Comment: [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/3110834)