# Upgrading WebBrowser class into WebView class in winforms application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

In my winforms application, I used `WebBrowser` class which is using `IE` browser. I want to update it into `WebView` class so that I can use `Edge` browser. That's why I installed packages `Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView`. Then I changed some existing code which is compatible with `WebView`. But when I ran the project, I found the below errors after installing that package.

> The item "C:\Projects\windows-v2\packages\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.4.6.0\build\net461....\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" in item list "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.

Comment: Looks like you are looking into the wrong package. You need to install `Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView`.

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake. Actually I installed that package. I updated the text.

Comment: Do you have any idea about the mentioned error? I followed the same steps as you described in your answers. @RezaAghaei

Comment: I tried in a clean solution/project without any problem. So I suggest you create a clean solution/project and give it a try.

Comment: Yeah clean solution is working. But problem with existing solution.

Comment: It's pretty hard to guess what's going on in your local project. In such cases, I may clean up the packages folder and after making sure about using correct package version, restore packages.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution and I am answering my own question. If anyone will face same problem then it will help.

The problem is not in the code. It is a problem in visual studio upgrading problem. Previously the project was in VS 2015 version but when I upgraded the `webView`, I used VS 2017 version. This is the reason to show the error `"ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal"`.

To solve this problem go to the following directory:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`
and open `Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` file.
Then at `Line 3961` change this `...Include="@(ReferencePath)"` into `...Include="@(ReferencePath.CopyLocal)"`

Comment: Huh?  Go to a folder, then a line number?  I am not following.  Would you clarify please.  Thanks...

Comment: My mistake. forgot to add the name of the file. Edited. BTW thanks for reminder.

Comment: For 2019 VS is Line 3948, or better, you need to find tag <_CopyLocalFalseRefPaths>

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I also had to Migrate packages.config to PackageReference

Answer (score 2):

To use a  [`WebViewCompatible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webviewcompatible?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) control in a Windows Forms application:

1. Install package [`Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView)
2. Right click on an empty area in Toolbox → select *Choose Items* → From the *Choose Toolbox Items* → choose *.NET Framework Component* tab → Click on *Browse* → Browse the package folder and choose `Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.WebView` dll → Click *Open* → Click *OK*
3. Drop an instance of `WebViewCompatible` control on the form.
4. In the `Load` event or in constructor after `InitializeComponent` add code to navigate to the address you want:

   ```
   webViewCompatible1.Navigate("https://www.google.com");
   ```