# InnerHtml of Template tag returnes null in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a `WebBrowser` control on a WinForm form, which should show a specific HTML page. Within the HTML page, I have some `<template>`s that should be used to populate the page. When I use the following code:

```
string template = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("template-id").InnerHtml
```

I get `null`, instead of the actual inner HTML.

I guess it has to do with the fact that the `template` tag is not supported in old IE versions, hence in the `WebBrowser` control. How can I fix it? Is it even possible?

Of course, I could put my template into a string and be done with it, but this seems very hacky.

Thanks!

Comment: The windows forms browser control is based on the IE rendering engine (MSHTML, not EdgeHTML) which does not support the `<template>` element. If you want support for that you'll have to use a custom browser embed such as chromium. Moreover it defaults to compatibility mode IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebBrowser control uses Internet Explorer and Internet Explorer doesn't support `<template>` tag. (See [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)) section.

### If you can modify content of pages

If you can modify content of pages, there are some workaround for you to be able to use `<template>` tag. You can use either of the following options:

1. **Option 1 - Make the tag hidden and load IE in edge mode**

   ```
   webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Test</title>
       <meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=Edge"" />
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1>Test</h1>
       <div>This is a test page.</div>
       <template id=""template1"" style=""display:none;"">
           <h2>Flower</h2>
           <img src=""img_white_flower.jpg"" />
       </template>
   </body>
   </html>";
   webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (obj, args) =>
   {
       var element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("template1");
       MessageBox.Show(element?.InnerHtml);
   };
   ```
2. **Option 2 - Include [The HTML5 Shiv](https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv) in the page**

   ```
   webBrowser1.DocumentText = @"
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Test</title>
       <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src=""https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"">
       </script>
       <![endif]-->
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1>Test</h1>
       <div>This is a test page.</div>
       <template id=""template1"">
           <h2>Flower</h2>
           <img src=""img_white_flower.jpg"" />
       </template>
   </body>
   </html>";
   webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (obj, args) =>
   {
       var element = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("template1");
       MessageBox.Show(element?.InnerHtml);
   };
   ```

### If you cannot modify content of pages

If you cannot modify content of the page, you need to use a different browser control, for example:

1. You can use the new [WebViewCompatible control for Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webviewcompatible?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). You can see simple steps to use here: [Replace WebBrowser control by new WebView Compatible control for Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59271260/3110834). It will use Edge rendering engine on Windows 10, but for other windows versions, it uses IE again.
2. You can rely on other You can rely on other browser controls like [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp).