# Unable to build WinForms app due to "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal"

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

`"...\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" in item list "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.`

I'm unable to build WinForms app after adding WebView copomenent to it due to above error. I've found possible solutions like migrate package.config to PackageReference or adding `CopyLocal` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets` file. None of them works for me.

`System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.targets` file in the project look like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(DoNotReferenceWinRT)' != 'true'">
      <!-- 
        ResolveAssemblyReference was attempting to write binding redirects
        for these assemblies (even though they are in the unification list).
      -->
      <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- ...include the reference to System.Runtime -->
        <DependsOnNETStandard>true</DependsOnNETStandard>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <ReferencePath Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll">
          <!-- Private = false to make these reference only -->
          <Private>false</Private>
          <!-- given this package does not have NugetPackage metadata it will not show in solution explorer, making it explicit -->
          <Visible>false</Visible>
        </ReferencePath>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
  <!-- when this package is referenced as a nuget reference the binding redirect is still present, add a target to remove it -->
  <Target Name="_RemoveWindowsRuntimeSuggestedRedirect" 
      BeforeTargets="GenerateBindingRedirects" 
      DependsOnTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences"
      Condition="'$(DoNotReferenceWinRT)' != 'true'">
    <ItemGroup> 
      <SuggestedBindingRedirects Remove="System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /> 
    </ItemGroup> 
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I'm using latest Visual Studio 2019 Professional.

Comment: remove `<CopyLocal>true</CopyLocal>`

Comment: it was actually added by me but it changes nothing

Comment: Please refer to the similar issue [Upgrading WebBrowser class into WebView class in winforms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269515/upgrading-webbrowser-class-into-webview-class-in-winforms-application) to check if it can solve your problem.