# Object Error while using browser object in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

My application is a windows application. I am using web browser control in my VN.NET application. I receive an unlatched error at line `Application.DoEvent()` after `webbrowser.navigate()`.

It would be very helpful if someone solved this error. [screenshot of error dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udYiW.png)

Comment: First thing, don't use `Application.DoEvent()` (if you think you need it it's because you're not doing something the way you should), then set the `ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true` and also modify the WebBrowser compatibility mode as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/7444103).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not post screenshots of error messages. Waste 1 minute of your time and transcribe the message using markdown.