# Is there WinForms control for Chromium-Edge HTML renderer?

Tags: .net, winforms, microsoft-edge, chromium, webview2

Microsoft has recently released Edge browser which uses Chromium engine to render HTML.
Is there a WinForms component which allows to embed it in a desktop application?

I'm aware of [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) for WinForms, just looking if there's something supported natively.

Comment: [Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2) developer preview is available for Win32 C++ on Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows 8, and Windows 7. In the future, it will be planned to support WebView2 on .NET, and XAML.

Comment: If you are looking for Microsoft Edge (NOT Chromium Edge) support for Windows Forms, you may want to use [`WebViewCompatible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webviewcompatible?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: What is the reason for CefSharp not satisfying your needs?

Comment: Probably → *just looking if there's something supported natively.*

Comment: I'm currently successfully using the WebView control with a .NET WinForms program. I tried WebViewCompatible but wasn't satisfied with it. I will attempt to migrate to WebView2 when it is released.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### WebView2

The [Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) control enables you to host web content in your application using Microsoft Edge (Chromium) as the rendering engine.

The control is available on the following programming environments:

- Win32 C/C++ (GA)
- .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later
- .NET Core 3.1 or later
- .NET 5

### Getting started with WebView2

1. Install prerequisites on your machine:

   - [WebView2 Runtime](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
   - [Microsoft Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
2. Create a Windows Forms Application.
3. Install WebView2 [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) in your project.
4. Drop an instance of the WebView2 from toolbox on your form.
5. Set the Source property to a valid URL like: Https://bing.com and run the application.

**More information**

- [Getting started with WebView2 in Windows Forms apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms)
- [Sample WinForms Application - GitHub Repository](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples)
- [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.winforms.webview2?&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) class reference.

*Note:* `WebView2` will replace the `WebView` control in the [toolkit](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32). `WebView` has already been marked as obsolete.

Comment: it seems it is now available for .Net: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#getting-started

Comment: @ASh Thanks for the info, I'll check it later, however if you have already checked it, feel free to apply an edit :)

Comment: there is definitely a github repo with samples for WinForms and WPF. I haven't tried them yet

Comment: @ASh Updated the post, however I couldn't run the example because of a null reference exception. But I assume it's stable enough as Preview.

Comment: @RezaAghaei null reference exception is probably raised because you dont have runtime installed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#the-webview2-runtime

Comment: @Nikola  As far as I remember the issue was temporary, and I don't have any issue at the moment. But as you see in the post the first step is pointing out installation of prerequisites :)