# Report Manager URL not working in 4.5 framework web browser

Tags: .net, winforms, reporting-services, ssrs-2019

I have .NET WinForms app and created a form which have we browser control(System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser)   to open Report manager. Reporting services 2019 report manager is not loading in Web browser. Is there anyway if I can default to Edge to open report manager? Report manager works fine if we open in Edge or chrome browser but not in Winform app System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.

Comment: Set up [WebBrowser to show modern content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/3110834), or use [WebView2 in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59960888/3110834).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webview2 is the successor of WebView and uses edge (chromium) as the render engine instead of Internet explorer (trident).

Comment: we are using visual studio 2013 and .NET 4.5 framework. I cannot find it in toolbox after adding reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms

Comment: Webview2 is supported in Visual Studio 2015 or higher. You will need to upgrade Visual Studio in order to use Webview2.