# How to add HTML code into your windows forms

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I'm making custom app and I would like to show something like this in my windows form, eg. in panel.

```
<iframe src="http://www.game-state.com/iframe.php?ip=94.23.164.84&port=7777&bgcolor=363636&bordercolor=26A8FF&fieldcolor=FFFFFF&valuecolor=EDEDED&oddrowscolor=4D4D4D&showgraph=true&showplayers=true&graphvalues=EDEDED&graphaxis=FFFFFF&width=220&graph_height=105&plist_height=101&font_size=9" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 220px; height: 371px"></iframe>
```

Is it possible?

Also I found this, but it doesn't work

```
panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<iframe src='mypage.aspx'></iframe>"));
```

Comment: Seems like you want a WebBrowser control...

Comment: ...and most probably also this: [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/7444103)

Comment: Thank you for answers, WebBrowser control works like a charm for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514184/how-can-i-get-the-webbrowser-control-to-show-modern-contents)