# Problems with ScrollBar and WebBrowser in Visual c #

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am making a web browser in Visual C #, all good so far, but I have a little problem, well ... a problem, when I load pages like Wikipedia, Facebook etc, (ANY WEB PAGE), the scrollbar has a bug, gltch or something like that ... here is a picture of the problem ...

A second scroll bar appears, which I do not want, since when I use it, the page moves badly, weird and even causes problems

I have tried everything, remove the tabStop, remove the displacement bar, or even try with different codes in Form1_load, but nothing solves it, I hope you can tell me or at least give me an answer on how to solve it, I spent 2 months with this ! ..

```
private void ConnectedClient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Navegar para página inicial
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate("www.bing.com");

        // atualizar os botões Forward/Back
        AtualizaBotoes();

        // pronto
        this.statusText.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

here is a reference.

Comment: Check your tags please.  Might get better responses with the C# tag instead of vb.net

Comment: [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/7444103)