# VB.NET Webbrowser not Displaying website when i type www.messenger.com

Tags: vb.net

So Im trying to Display Messenger in my Webbrowser but sadly messenger website is not displaying instead its displaying color white only in web browser here is the code that i used to display Messenger

```
    WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("www.messenger.com")
```

i already try using this

```
   WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
      WebBrowser1.Navigate(New Uri("https://www.messenger.com/"))
```

but Messenger website is still not displaying but google.com is working. So my question is why Google.com is working and messenger.com is not displaying

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514184/how-can-i-get-the-webbrowser-control-to-show-modern-contents)

Comment: You might want to use NuGet package WebView2 instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/