# Why does Checkbox tick keep showing as square?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

The checkbox tick of webbrowser and the scroll bar button keep showing as square.
This does not happen when with other PC.

I tried to load the HTML code in normal browser, all other browsers showed the tick correctly except
internet explorer.

I've searched for solutions online I couldn't get one.

[image: checkbox showing square]

[image: web browser scroll bar button showing as square]

Comment: are you using any js scripts for styling or as part of the check box?

Comment: [How can I show modern content with WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/3110834)

Answer (score 1):

It reminds me of [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/ie10-shows-square-blocks-on-every-dropdown-menu/068079a1-47ab-496a-8358-4391b564aaee), where the problem was solved by uninstalling and reinstalling **Segoe Symbol UI font**. You can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not the correct place for this question, my guess is you have a problem with your fonts since these characters are painted using fonts, Webdings or something like that if my memory serves me connect

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm sorry, where can this kind of question be asked? because if I had known, I would have done the right thing

Comment: no problem, I don't know where it should be either. Probably one of the following https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology

Answer (score 0):

IE is very outdated and therefore will have weird styles for lots of html elements, I do not know if this is the problem with this specific element but if it is, you can use -webkit-appearance: none; to stop the default style and then style it the way you want. Make sure to target the tick and not the checkbox by using a pseudo element. Hope that helps.