# <br> tag issue in webbrowser

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

When I try to add a `<br>` tag after table and open it using winforms control WebBrowser.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" width="100%"> <tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background:#ffb900;padding:5pt 2pt 5pt 2pt"></td>
<td width="100%" cellpadding="7px 6px 7px 15px" style="background:#fff8e5;padding:5pt 4pt 5pt 12pt;word-wrap:break-word">
<div style="color:#222222;"><span style="color:#222; font-weight:bold;">Caution:</span> Test caution here.
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<div>
<p>Test string here.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that it doesn't insert single line breaks in the text.

[image]

But it works in Edge and Chrome.

[image]

**Why?**

I know there are some workarounds to handle this issue, such as "add doube `<br>` after table"

```
</table>
<br>
<br>
<div>
```

or remove `align="left"`

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
```

However,**is there any way to solve this problem once and for all? Instead of manually modifying each html file.**

Comment: You can use margin bottom on table instead of br or margin-top on div

Comment: While I'd suggest you set the browser emulation using one of the suggested approaches below, but you should know you can fix the issue with removing `align="left"` from the table. Alternatively, you can use just one br, using `<br clear=""left""/>` next to it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for a decade or more.

Comment: A `<br>` element is inserted into the markup. However, a '<br>` element is a **line break** and you have no textual lines. So a break is inserted of zero height as expected.

Comment: @Rob it's It's just fine to use `<br/>` however `/` is not mandatory. But in general it's an off-topic discussion for this thread. It doesn't have anything to do with the issue, or the solution. Further reading for the OP or anyone who is interested:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Comment: @RezaAghaei That's why it's a comment. Furthermore, the closing slash has no meaning, it does nothing, and browsers ignore it. So it's pointless and the W3C validator will warn you of it. A better link from the W3C would be [Trailing slashes](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements)

Answer (score 3):

You should add a meta-tag that specifies the emulation mode, setting it to Internet Explorer 11 (the latest version available in the System of IE):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

which gives you the expected behavior.
You can make a simple procedure that batch-adds this line right after `<head>` in your files.

If possible, probably better migrate to WebView2 to have the Edge-Chromium *experience*
See: [Introduction to Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/)

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob Removed. It doesn't matter much though

Comment: It's allowed for backwards compatibility. It does nothing, has no meaning, and browsers are instructed to ignore it. So it's pointless

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change HTML content, you can set the [browser emulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#browser-emulation) to a higher IE version, like IE11 Edge mode in code. For example when loading the form, before setting the browser content:

```
using (var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
    @"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
    true))
{
    var app = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    key.SetValue(app, 11001, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    key.Close();
}
```

For more information: [How can I get the WebBrowser control to show modern contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/3110834)