# How can I use DOMParser in an html file that contains a javascript function that is called using a C# web browser control?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms

I am able to invoke the method and set up the html file. The issue I'm having is that inside the html file I am using the DOMParser object in a javascript function that I'm calling in C#. It is not defined due to not using an actual browser.

Adding this line to the html file fixes the problem:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

The problem is I want to run the winforms application on an old Virtual Machine that doesn't contain Microsoft Edge..

Is there a way I can manually load the DOMParser object into my html file / javascript funtion?

Comment: The meta tag you're mentioning is related to Internet Explorer, it means *use the latest version available as the emulation mode*. Not related to Edge (Chromium) browsers, or the previous Edge version

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. I am able to run the app on Windows 10 but unable to run it on Windows 7 or older OS. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: The version of Internet Explorer you have in Windows 7 is not the same as the one you find in Windows 10. In Windows 7, you may also need to [register your executable in the Features Browser Emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514446/7444103) section of the registry -- Note that [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) is available for Windows 7. It would solve all your compatibility problems (all this assuming the Windows 7 System is updated to the last available security patches, otherwise all possible solutions become quite irrelevant)