# WPF WebBrowser-Control open Link in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I use the WebBrowser-Control in my WPF-Application:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser">
</WebBrowser>
```

When I load a Document which contains a Link and the User clicks on this Link, the Link will be loaded in the old InternetExplorer instead of the Defaultbrowser. Is it possible to change this behaviour?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38514184/how-can-i-get-the-webbrowser-control-to-show-modern-contents/38514446#38514446. Switch to `WebView2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use the OnNavigating-Event to process the Click yourself.

Comment: No, the Event will not be executed with this link.